# Having trouble running Steam

Tags: boot, command-line, 64-bit, steam, 32-bit

I'm new to Ubuntu and have no idea how the terminal works. My main issue is Steam not loading and it keeps telling me to upgrade my system from 32-bit to 64-bit, but how?

Comment: Well it's quite clear. You installed a 32 bit version of Ubuntu instead of 64bit. You need to download Ubuntu again but make sure it's the 64bit (AMD64) version, mount it to USB or DVD and when I'm the installer, you might be able to upgrade it. I'm not sure, I've never tried upgrading from a 32bit arch. If not just reinstall but keep all your files (if that option is also available

Comment: @xR34P3Rx: Could you please write that as an answer instead of a comment? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well it's quite clear. You installed a 32 bit version of Ubuntu instead of 64bit. You need to download Ubuntu again but make sure it's the 64bit (AMD64) version, mount it to USB or DVD and when I'm the installer, you might be able to upgrade it. I'm not sure, I've never tried upgrading from a 32bit arch. If not just reinstall but keep all your files (if that option is also available

Ubuntu 17.04 64bit - http://releases.ubuntu.com/17.04/ubuntu-17.04-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent

Comment: but what do i do after i download the torrent?

Comment: oh, thats a torrent link, lol. This is the link to the ISO. - http://releases.ubuntu.com/17.04/ubuntu-17.04-desktop-amd64.iso?_ga=2.163458556.1524610621.1506368940-802840240.1504906983

Comment: The torrent link is for downloading via a Bitorrent Client like uTorrent. That will download the ISO in a P2P network.